# Permanent Picture Uploads

Tags: feature-request, images

I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/question-regarding-weierstrass-m-test) and in the process found that I could not access the corresponding image as it was hosted on imgur. Is there any solution for the above? 
(The questions contains a link image which has been probably now been deleted by the imgur site.) 
[The imgur policy](https://imgur.com/faq#long) on deletion of images is

> As long as images are getting at least 1 view every 6 months, they will stick around forever. After that, your image may be removed to create more space for newer images.

In that sense, can there be a feature designed so that the images linked to imgur are visited every 5 months or so by the site itself? Or should we systematically discourage people to use links to images as such as instead ask them to upload the image using the Image function of the stackexchange software?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: There were already some question concerning uploading images, e.g. when you search for [imgur](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=imgur) you find a few. Perhaps questions related to images and image hosting would deserve their own tag? (I did not find a suitable tag among the [tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags) which we already have.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yeah and I don't think I have the power to enable new tags. 
There is another question of the similar nature http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/are-uploaded-images-preserved-in-the-se-system. But the discussion there has apparently failed in this particular case.

Comment: I've managed to restore the image; the trick was to remove the `.stack` portion of the image's URL...

Comment: Ohh, that is nice :-).

Comment: I've created images tag - I hope it's a suitable name.

Comment: @J.M.: Did you re-upload the image or just remove `.stack`?  [This answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2484/72) seems to indicate that images with urls containing `.stack` are not "owned" by SE in imgur's system and thus subject to the 6-month removal, whereas ones uploaded through SE are "owned" by SE, wouldn't have `.stack`, and not subject to the 6-month removal.

Comment: @Isaac: I re-uploaded the image, using the "from the web" panel of the importer and using the `.stack`-less version of the URL as source. You can check the revision history...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Jeff's answer here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2484/72), images that have been uploaded through the StackExchange upload interface are not subject to the 6-month removal (they are hosted on imgur, but in a StackExchange account that does not have the restriction about needing traffic every few months).

Comment: So, should a proper answer be that we should try to encourage people to use ".stack"-less links to the images when inserting images "from the web"? May be we can give such a suggestion below or above the "link" url in the dialog box?

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik: My understanding is that the only images that were broken by having `.stack` inserted in the URL were ones uploaded to imgur before SE made their own image-upload system based on imgur.  That is, any new images should be uploaded using the insert image button in the post-editing toolbar (and in doing so, they will have the correct URL).

Comment: Ohk, thanks for the clarification..