# Animations in other format than .gif

Tags: feature-request, images

I sometimes like to include animations as part of my posts to add explanations to what I am doing. However it seems only .gif is the format for animations supported. Is there some way to include animations with more powerful compression like .apng .webm or even .avi?

I tried animated png and the preview works fine in browser but it seems imgur later turns it into a still image .jpg for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of some simple tests, APNG is supported but WebM is not.

APNG: [image: Bouncing ball]

WEBM: [image: Volcano]

The solution to using APNG is simple: use an image host which supports it. That includes imgur, although you may have to do the upload in a separate browser tab and then write the CommonMark markup manually: `![alt text](image url)`

Comment: Ah so I can use another host for apng. Great, thanks Peter.

Comment: I suppose the disadvantage of an alternative host is bigger likelihood of link rot. (Previous discussion: [Permanent Picture Uploads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4205).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, that's why I mentioned imgur. It's *not* an alternative host.

Comment: @PeterTaylor But still, if you upload to imgur directly and not through editor, you are losing the advantage mentioned in the post: "they are hosted on imgur, but in a StackExchange account that does not have the restriction about needing traffic every few months".