# Difficulties with displaying set signs

Tags: bug, mathjax

In the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876625/a-game-of-magic-egyptian-tilings) I recently asked, I wasn't able to the display the symbols denoting sets in mathematics: {, and }.

Usually, I write them by putting

```
$\{  \}$
```

But for some reason, this didn't work. Is this because of some update of the StackExchange software? Or is it a bug? And should I use different symbols to achieve the desired goal?

Comment: I was able to fix all instances for you in your post, and the code displayed completely correctly for me the entire time (both during the edit and after submitting the edit). I suspect this is an instance of the occasional bugs affecting MathJax that are reported on Meta every so often?

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for the fixes. Not sure what happened in my case - you may be right about the occasional bugs. It also happened when I tried tagging the equations.

Comment: Is it just in the preview, or in the final post too? If the problem is only in the preview, it might be the same bug which was reported a few times. 
On this meta: [Escaped braces do not render in post preview](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31124).
On MathOverflow Meta: [Braces are not rendered in MathJax in the preview of a question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5163)
On [meta.se]: [MathJax escape sequences don't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387653)